# Upload File: Comsuming WCF Web Service Using Java

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, upload

I have a WCF Web Service (.NET C#). And I want to consume that service by java client application.

I have a following code using that I am successfully able to connect with the Web Service. But now I am facing problem with uploadFile method.

When I am passing string to the request entity then it call the web service method but as I passed/set FileInputStream RequestEntity then it throw exception ...

> Connection reset by peer: socket write error

My Java Client Code is as following....

- Please ignore: logging is not added here...

  ```
      public void consumeService(){
          String sXML = null;
          String sURI = URI + "/upload";
          sXML = item;
          HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap();
          header.put("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

          File file = new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\P1130503.JPG");
          try {

             RequestEntity requestEntity= new InputStreamRequestEntity(
                      new FileInputStream(sFile), InputStreamRequestEntity.CONTENT_LENGTH_AUTO);
              for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
              String key = entry.getKey();
              String value = entry.getValue();
              headers.addHeader(key, value);
              }
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(C3Service.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }


          HttpMethodBase httpPostRequest = new PostMethod(url + buildParams());
          HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
          try {
              // add headers
              Iterator it = headers.entrySet().iterator();
              while (it.hasNext()) {
              Entry header = (Entry) it.next();
              httpPostRequest.addRequestHeader((String) header.getKey(), (String) header.getValue());

              }
             ((PostMethod) httpPostRequest).setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
              try {
              respCode = client.executeMethod(httpPostRequest);
              System.out.println("Response Code  "+respCode);
              response = httpPostRequest.getResponseBodyAsString();
              this.responsePhrase = httpPostRequest.getStatusText();
              System.out.println("Response  "+response);
              System.out.println("Response Phase  "+responsePhrase);

            }catch(Exception ex){
                  System.out.println("ErrorS "+ex.toString());
              } finally {
                //  resp.close();
              httpPostRequest.releaseConnection();
              }
          }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("ErrorD "+ex.toString());
          }
          finally {
              //client.c
          }
    }
  ```

NOTE: when I passed string and set StringRequestEntity then it working file.

```
 new StringRequestEntity(statusAsXml, "text/plain", Constants.DEFAULT_ENCODING)
```

**C# CODE**

IService

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "upload")]
        bool upload(Stream relativePath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer. It was the matter of assigning valid content type. I was setting content type

```
 header.put("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

After using following content-type, I am able to upload file successfully

```
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
```